# $fb->fileToUpload($imageName) not working properly

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to upload the photo to user's profile through my code. Below is the code I am using:

```
echo $imageName;

$data = [
'message' => 'Visit http://www.mywebsite.com',
'source' => $fb->fileToUpload($imageName),
];

echo 'hi1';

try {
 // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
}

echo 'hi';
```

In above code echo `$imageName` is printing the required image name (variable contains desired value say images/abc.jpg) but when use the following it is not working:

```
$fb->fileToUpload($imageName)
```

If I remove variable name and give direct value like so it is working fine:

```
$fb->fileToUpload("images/abc.jpg") .
```

Can you please help me with whats wrong with my code.

Comment: What error message do you get? Do possibly have a gist? I could help you out more then.

Answer (score 1):

Provide full path of image(http://example.com/image/1.jpg)
Try below one.
This is tested in version 5

```
    require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

     $app_ID = 'xxxxxxxxx';
     $APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
     $access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => $app_ID,
      'app_secret' => $APP_SECRET,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
      ]);
    $data = [
      'message' => 'My photo upload example.',
      'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('http://example.com/images/1.jpg'),
    ];

    try {
      $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, $access_token);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

just try with concatenation like $fb->fileToUpload('"'.$imageName.'"');